# How do I change the text of a password element input JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want programmatically input password with JavaScript. I'm use this code

```
document.getElementById('password').value='Hh1234567';
```

When I click the submit button, it shows an error: "password is required please input password". But when input password with manually with the keybord it works fine.

How can I make it accept my password entered via the script?

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting the value of the password field doesn't alone create the event necessary for the change of that value to be detected, so you need something like this:

```
  const pwd = document.getElementById('password');
  pwd.value = 'Hh1234567';
  pwd.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
```